# JQuery ajax GET request to URL fails although HTTP status is 200 OK

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I apologize if this question has already been answered.

I am trying to retrieve data from a REST web service that exposes a JSON interface using jQuery .ajax call.

When I call the service using the URL, the jQuery call fails although I get a HTTP status code 200 OK.

When I copy the response into a file on the filesystem and retrieve this, the same call works.

Both the file I am accessing and the web service I am calling are on the same machine.

Some notes on the url used in the code below:

Using:

```
url: "http://localhost:9090/app/user/861",
```

the call fails, goes into .fail on all browsers.

The URL itself returns the json on all browsers:

```
{
    "userid": 861,
    "employeeno": "123",
    "jobdesc": "Developer",
    "firstname": "Jasper",
    "lastname": "Fitussi"
}
```

when using "test.json" in the local filesystem following is the behavior:

```
url: "ajax/test.json",
```

On Firefox, the call executes, goes into .done  and displays the result on page.

On Chrome, the call fails with status 404 and the following message -

"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

I tried different combinations changing `dataType:"jsonp"`, adding a `?callback=?` to the end of the URL, and enclosing the data in the test.json with a '(' and a ')' without luck.

Please understand I am new to UI programming, javascript and jQuery.

Please help with what I am doing wrong. Here's the javascript:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"ajax/test.json",    
            // the following commented call fails, goes into .fail
            // url:"http://localhost:9090/app/user/861", 
            contentType: "application/json",
            accepts: "application/json",
            dataType: "json"
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("Success");
            console.log(data);
            var items = [];
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
            });
            $( "<ul/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list",
                html: items.join( "" )
            }).appendTo( "body" );
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("Failed");
            })
        .always(function() {
            alert("In Always");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The following is the output when I paste the url into the browser (also the contents of ajax/test.json):

```
{
    "userid": 861,
    "employeeno": "123",
    "jobdesc": "Developer",
    "firstname": "Jasper",
    "lastname": "Fitussi"
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find you have a strange url somewhere. Almost every modern browser enforces restrictions on `ajax`ing from other origins (url domains) than the site is currently hosted at. Try changing your url to `"/test.json"`, I think that has a better chance of working. Otherwise examine your urls carefully.

Comment: Also, make sure you are making the request from a served page, something that starts with http:// and not something that starts with file://

Comment: I tried moving the file into a folder, as well as tried using a served page from tomcat running on localhost, but the behavior is the same as described above. My goal is to retrieve data from the served page - this does not work from any browser. So is localhost not the same domain?

Comment: Is localhost the same domain for the ajax request and the document it originates from?

Comment: Please clearly quote the number of issues you are facing, seems like you have specified 404 as well as 200 with failure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not about UI programming, it's about the security model of modern browsers :p

Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors occurs when you call a webservice (ie: load a JSON file) from a domain that is different from the one hosting your HTML page.
In your case, you are opening the html file from your hard drive (file:///) and calling a webservice on localhost.

This is a security feature in all modern browsers that forbid getting data from a foreign webservice without the webservice owners authorizing you (or everyone, wildcards are allowed) to call it.

I recommend reading the following guide from MDN, so that you understand WHY you are having this problem.
It will then be easy to resolve

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

If you control the source code of the webservice, or the webserver hosting it, you need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP headers.

Comment: I finally now understand the problem and the solution, and am able to appreciate the security model better. The following resources helped me get around the problem. http://vivin.net/2011/07/01/implementing-jsonp-in-spring-mvc-3-0-x/

Comment: Good! Remember thought that JSONP is a (very) convenient workaround for Cross Origin queries but is somewhat limited. No error handling client side, no POST/PUT/DELETE etc... On the long term i recommend using Allow-Origin headers instead

Answer (score 0):

Do you make your ajax call using Apache on wamp, lamp, xampp or mamp or not? I think you work directly using some files lets say on your desktop and not from the www file of wamp. If the browser sends a correct url then the backend responds great, your frontend code seems fine so i think chrome complains about your not using localhost. Am i right? Whats your local development setup?

Comment: The webservice is developed using java (spring) running on Tomcat on the local machine(my PC). I am not able to retrieve data from this webservice using the jquery ajax call. I can hit the URL directly from the browser or with a REST Client on the browser and get the json response with no problem.

Comment: You can check using dev tools, the Request URL, the Request Headers => Accept and the Response Headers =>  Content-Type if they are application/json and the Request => Host if it is 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local file on the client-side, use `file:///` to prefix the URL:

```
url: 'file:///ajax/test.json'
```

The third `/` in `file:///` indicates:

> As a special case,  can be the string "localhost" or the empty 
>   string; this is interpreted as `the machine from which the URL is
>   being interpreted'. 
>   3.10

### [Reference here](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/quality/networking/testing/filetests.html)

Comment: Hi, Changing the URL to include file:/// did not change the behavior as I mentioned in the original question. I still get a failed with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header..." error on Chrome, and a successful execution on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Download a tool called fiddler, from http://fiddler2.com/ great way to debug web requests and to see why they are failing. 
This will help you narrow down the issue you are experiencing and we can help you further because currently its all guess work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, all worked fine in I.E and FireFox, a had one ajax call to a rest service using jsonp and it worked fine in chrome, however when I tried to load a file using jsonp I got the cross domain error. In short i had to add "file:" to my file path in the url

```
    $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'file:jsondata/rain_acc_data.json',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback : "jsoncallback",
    success : function(data) {
        aler('ok');
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, status) {
        alert("Failed to load list" + status + jqXHR);
    }
});
```

this worked for me, make sure to wrap your json in the file with jsoncallback("your jason here");