# AJAX JSONP Failure returns statustext "success", correct callback

Tags: python, ajax, json, iis, jsonp

I know this has been asked before but can't seem to figure it out. I have a IIS 6.0 server hosting a python script. This is what the python script returns...
It converts a list of dictionaries to a json object, sets the header and returns the data.

```
try:
    name
    allergy = json.dumps(sorted(var_allergies, key=operator.itemgetter('name'),reverse=True))    
    print "Content-type: application/json"
    print
    print allergy

My ajax call is: 
    function AllergyPyJSON() {
        var url ="http://hostname/cgi-bin/allergies.py?callback=?"
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: { 'user_id': $('#user').val() },
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            jsonp: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp', 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
            success: function (json) {           
                alert(json)
            }
        }).done(function (r) {
            //alert('done');
        }).fail(function (r) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(r));
        })
    }
```

The response hits the fail method.
{"readyState:4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

If I use a debugger or look at chrome - console - network... I see the call and the response of

```
[{"date": "2014-02-20 10:49:47", "reaction": "None", "name": "Dilantin"}]
```

So it is calling the function and returning the correct data. 
How can I access the data in the callback? Or why is it failing and still returning data?

EDIT HERE is the return HEADERS

```
Remote Address:100.100.200.200:80
Request URL:http://server/cgi-bin/allergies.py?callback=?&pat_id=0009689&_=1406123902467
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:hh-borpt
Referer:http://localhost:42972/Forms/page.htm
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
callback:?
pat_id:0009689
_:1406123902467
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 23 Jul 2014 13:58:20 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
```

EDIT I figured it out:
I needed to include `jsonpCallback: 'jsoncallback'` in my ajax call

On the python side

```
print "Content-type: application/json"
print
print "jsonCallback(%s)" % allergy
```

Now it returns the data wrapper in a function (padded) and it's working. The success function fires with a json object.

```
jsonCallback({"date": "2014-02-20 10:49:47", "reaction": "None", "name": "Dilantin"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT I figured it out: I needed to include jsonpCallback: 'jsoncallback' in my ajax call

And in my python code I have to include the function name around the json object.

```
print "Content-type: application/json"
print
print "jsonCallback(%s)" % allergy
```

Now it returns the data wrapper in a function (padded) and it's working. The success function fires with a json object.

```
jsonCallback({"date": "2014-02-20 10:49:47", "reaction": "None", "name": "Dilantin"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your 'JsonPCallback', you claim that the callback should be a function called 'JsonCallback', but you haven't included that function in your post. Try removing that line, and just letting json flow to your success method that you have built already.

Try this instead:

```
function AllergyPyJSON() {
    var url ="http://hostname/cgi-bin/allergies.py?callback=?"
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: { 'user_id': $('#user').val() },
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        jsonp: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
        success: function (json) {           
            alert(json)
        }
    }).done(function (r) {
        //alert('done');
    }).fail(function (r) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(r));
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't include my jsoncallback. In any case, I removed the jsonpcallback line and let jquery create a random callback function.  The request url is Request URL:http://hh-borpt/cgi-bin/patientJSON.py?callback=jQuery110107081023941282183_1406126494685&pat_id=0009689&_=1406126494686


The data is:
{"lname": "IFORM", "mrn": "000104936", "patientid": "0009689", "fname": "TEST PATIENT"}. However the fail function was still called. It may be unrelated but the console is displaying : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Tried sending json.dumps("hello") on the python side. Console log is clean (no errors)... but the ajax fail still gets called.

Comment: are you absolutely sure that your Json is valid? Could also be a local header issue, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847008/jquery-ajax-get-request-to-url-fails-although-http-status-is-200-ok

Comment: It wasn't valid... it was expecting to receive back a json object wrapped in a function (jsonp) and I was only sending it a json object. Look at my last edit to see how it was resolved. I had to specify the callback name, and in python include that function name in my print statement... after that it started working.